# PostgreSQL: How to define function in declare block?

Tags: database, postgresql

```
CREATE FUNCTION outer_function(param1 DATE) RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
FUNCTION inner_function1 IS
BEGIN
    -- do something to calculate output_day
    RAISE NOTICE 'INNER FUNCTION';
END;
FUNCTION inner_function2 IS
BEGIN
    -- do something to calculate output_day
    RAISE NOTICE 'INNER FUNCTION';
END;
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'OUTER FUNCTION BODY';
 -- call inner_function1
 inner_function1;
 -- call inner_function2
 inner_function2;

RETURN 'TRUE';
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

How to define function in declare block?
I have to define function in declaration block and call it from begin.
Kindly suggest is it possible in postgresql

Comment: That's not possible.